# if I use angularJS $state.go to another state, will the target state's controller be treaded as the child of the initial controller?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am asking this because i found after the $state.go statement if use $scope.emit in the target page's controller, the initial page's controller $state.$on can not receive the message sometimes.

Anyway I noticed this behavior does not occur on every controllers, so this is confusing me.

Let's take 3 controllers from my projects as an example, both Ctrl1 and Ctrl2 will have a state.go to Ctrl3.

Ctrl1:

```js
var NewsCtrl = function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $q, $location, $state, $stateParams, $sce, $ionicHistory, $ionicViewService) {


  $rootScope.$on('updateNewsLocalViewsCount', function(event, data) {      
    console.log('##root scope receiving updateNewsLocalViewsCount:' + event +  ':' + JSON.stringify(data));

  });


  $scope.$on('updateNewsLocalViewsCount', function(event, data) {      
    console.log('#scope receiving updateNewsLocalViewsCount:' + event +  ':' + JSON.stringify(data));
  });

  $scope.gotoNotifications = function() {
    $state.go("app.notifications");
  };


};
```

```html
<button 
class="button-icon" 
ng-click="gotoNotifications()">notifications
</button>
```

Ctrl2:

```js
var LeadsCtrl = function($cordovaNetwork, $cordovaPreferences, $ionicPlatform, $localStorage, $rootScope, 
                            $cordovaStatusbar, $state, $location,  $translate,
                            $ionicLoading) {

      $rootScope.$on('LeadSavedAsCustomer', function(event, data) {
        console.log('#root scope receiving Leads Ctrl-LeadSavedAsCustomer-' + event +  ':' + JSON.stringify(data) + ' DO NOTHING ');
      });

      $scope.$on('LeadSavedAsCustomer', function(event, data) {
        console.log('#scope receiving Leads Ctrl-LeadSavedAsCustomer-' + event +  ':' + JSON.stringify(data) + ' DO NOTHING ');
      });

      $scope.gotoNotifications = function() {
        $state.go("app.notifications");
      };


    };
```

```html
<button 
class="button-icon" 
ng-click="gotoNotifications()">
notifications
</button>
```

Ctrl3:

```js
var NotificationsCtrl = function($scope) {


  $scope.$emit('updateNewsLocalViewsCount', {"newsid":"1", "counts":"1"});


  $scope.$emit('LeadSavedAsCustomer', {"customerId": "1", "leadId": "1"});


}
```

RESULT:

**in Ctrl1: Only the $rootScope.$on was invoked.**

**in Ctrl2: Both the $rootScope.$on and $scope.$on were invoked.**

But actually these controllers are quite similar. Not sure why the behaviors are different..

will the state.go or html  make parent/child relationships automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, is your `NotificationsCtrl` inside your `LeadsCtrl`? In that case, the former would be a child of the latter. And it would trigger on `$scope.$on`. Read more about [Scope Hierarchy in AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

> Nesting controllers using ng-controller results in normal prototypal inheritance, just like ng-include and ng-switch, so the same techniques apply. If you really want to share data via controllers scope inheritance, there is nothing you need to do. The child scope will have access to all of the parent scope properties.

Comment: actually no, all these controllers are separated controllers which means they all have their own html file with no nested struct.. based on the angular sample i can see nested controller can emit data to parent. but in practice seems can also emit message to parent when using $state.go or <a href>. quite a few doc about this ..